# Why is Tweepy saying a retweet is a quote?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

Here's a simplified version of the code to reproduce the problem:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

consumer_key    = '...'
consumer_secret = '...'
access_token    = '...'
access_secret   = '...'

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
tweepy_api = tweepy.API(auth)

status_id = 999280226994671616
status = tweepy_api.get_status(status_id, tweet_mode='extended')

print(status.user.screen_name) # Prints 'VP' as it should

if status.retweeted: # Is false, even though it's a retweet
    print('RETWEET:', status.retweeted_status.full_text)
elif status.is_quote_status: # Is true
    qstatus = tweepy_api.get_status(status.quoted_status_id, tweet_mode='extended')
    print(status.full_text, '\nQUOTE:', qstatus.full_text) # Doesn't print full text for either status
else:
    print(status.full_text)
```

I'm wondering if the reason `is_quote_status` is true is because the retweet contains a quote. How do I detect whether the status is a retweet, then?

This is a secondary problem, but as my comments point out, it's also not displaying the full text (it does just fine when the status isn't a retweet or quote). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A retweet is a tweet, and a tweet may quote another tweet, so a retweet can quote a tweet.

In your case :

The tweet id 999280226994671616 is from @vp.

It is a retweet of the tweet id 999275458796687360 from @SecondLady (https://twitter.com/SecondLady/status/999275458796687360).

And this tweet is quoting the tweet id 999013390528937991 from @SenEvanBayh (https://twitter.com/SenEvanBayh/status/999013390528937991)

To know if a tweet is a RT, check if the status has the attribute retweeted_status.

This :

```
status_id = 999280226994671616
status = tweepy_api.get_status(status_id, tweet_mode='extended')

print ('status.id_str:' + status.id_str)
print ('status.user.screen_name:@' + status.user.screen_name)
print()

if hasattr(status, 'retweeted_status'):
    print ('status.retweeted_status.user.screen_name:' + status.retweeted_status.user.screen_name)
    print ('status.retweeted_status.id_str:' + status.retweeted_status.id_str)
    print()

    qstatus = tweepy_api.get_status(status.retweeted_status.quoted_status_id, tweet_mode='extended')
    print ('qstatus.id_str:' + qstatus.id_str)
    print ('qstatus.user.screen_name:@' + qstatus.user.screen_name)
    print()
```

will print :

```
status.id_str:999280226994671616
status.user.screen_name:@VP

status.retweeted_status.user.screen_name:SecondLady
status.retweeted_status.id_str:999275458796687360

qstatus.id_str:999013390528937991
qstatus.user.screen_name:@SenEvanBayh
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I read that the retweeted attribute should be sufficient. Apparently not.